# c++ if else text program won't go to the pathway I want it to

Tags: c++, eclipse, if-statement

I am trying to make a if else pathway with c++. What I want to happen is when I choose Anakin, then the bool "Anakin" will = true, then "if Anakin == true" it will output the desired code, and when I choose Heather, then "Anakin == false" and it will do the same. Except when I choose "Heather", it outputs the code as if I chose "Anakin":

```
bool anakin;
char Name[25];
string choice;
int GameState;
int iRoomCounter[4] = { 0, 0, 0 }; // Used to determine if a room has been
visited.int main()
{
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\tNimbus Town" << endl;
    cout << "What is your name?" << endl;
    cout << "Name: ";
    cin >> Name;
    cout << "All right " << Name << ", I will let you choose a friend that will be with" << endl;
    cout << "you along the way, okay? Great." << endl;
    cout << "Now choose your friend:" << endl;
    cout << "• Heather" << endl;
    cout << "• Anakin" << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == "Heather") {
        anakin = false;
        cout << "You chose Heather, good choice!" << endl;
        GameState = START;
    }
    else if (choice == "Anakin") {
        anakin = true;
        cout << "Anakin, what a great choice!" << endl;
        GameState = START;
    }
    else {
        cout << "What?" << endl;
    }

    while (GameState != DEATH) {
        switch (GameState) {
        case START: {

            if (iRoomCounter[0] == 0) {
                if (anakin == true) {
                    cout << "\n'Hello, welcome to Nimbus town.'" << endl;
                    cout << "You jolted awake as an older, white-haired" << endl;
                    cout << "man greeted you. He was in a white tuxedo." << endl;
                    cout << "'My name is Kieran. What about you?'" << endl;
                    cout << "My name is " << Name << "." << endl;
                    cout << "Well " << Name << ", it's nice to meet you." << endl;
                    cout << "\nsomething doesn't feel right about him, but it's probably" << endl;
                    cout << "because I'm new here, you thought." << endl;
                    iRoomCounter[0] = 1;
                    if (anakin == false) {
                        cout << "Anakin is falseo." << endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate it if someone told me what I'm supposed to do or give advice/code to help me.
Thank you!

Comment: `#include <string>` at the top of your code and use the string class instead of a char array

Comment: Begin by chopping out code. If the probl m goes away, put back the code that you removed and chop out something else. If the problem is still there, chop some more. Continue u till you can't remove any more code.

Comment: Also you are using == instead of = when assigning Anakin to true

Comment: @Leeor What please??

Comment: @Leeor "if (choice == "Anakin") - you can't compare strings like that" - of course you can.

Comment: @EastonBornemeier What char do I replace?

Comment: @EastonBornemeier I tried = but it didn't change anything.

Comment: `Name` is currently a char array of size 25. You can just use a string for simplicity, and even better, the string library built for cpp. Read more about it here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_strings.htm it will illustrate the difference between cstrings and strings

Comment: You also need to add an else to `if (choice == "Anakin")` because you are changing the value of Anakin if Heather is selected so it will go into both if statements. so it would be `else if (choice == "Anakin")`

Comment: @EastonBornemeier Thank you Easton but that doesn't help my current question.

Comment: I'm aware, I'm simply here to `"give advice"` that you seek ;)

Comment: If you want to know more about the why a certain output is happening, please elaborate on what the output actually is and I can explain.

Comment: Oh yeah, thank you! :)

Comment: I'll change my current code to what I updated it to on the question than explain in the comments.

Comment: @EastonBornemeier Ok, so I changed my code and made it better and here's the ouput: Everything starts normal. I put my name in the input. Then when I choose Heather, I says what I want it to say, but it doesn't change whether Anakin is false or true. I still has the "output as if I chose Anakin." There are also 2 warnings that say "Anakin = true" and "Anakin = False" , So I think that the code ignores the "Anakin = true/false" part

Comment: `if (anakin = true) {` is another place where the difference between `=` and `==`is important.

Comment: The brackets on your if statements are screwed up where you are checking the value of `anakin`. make sure to close the `if (anakin == true) {` bracket in the proper place. Also, like @BoPersson said, you need to use the comparison operator within if statements (==), not the assignment operator (=)

Comment: Also your case statement doesn't need a `{` after it. I beleive that is why it is not freaking out with the lack of a closing bracket on that if statement i talked about earlier. Helpful tip: Practice really neat coding--It goes a looong way in the long run to catch little things like this.

Comment: For further help post your code on this resource instead and comment the link: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Easton Bornemeier Ok so I closed it in the proper place (Thank you for that :), but now, when I choose Heather, it finally outputs it correctly, but it repeats the output infinitely, I think it's because since Anakin stays true, so the cout keeps repeating.

Comment: Ok Thank you! @EastonBornemeier

Comment: @NeilButterworth, sorry, for some reason I thought it was c (managed to miss the couts as well...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now You are doing assignments in your if statements.
In if statements use == since you want to check if a value matches.
When assigning new value use =
So for example
When assigning

```
anakin = true;
```

And

```
if (anakin == false)
```

When comparing

Comment: When I do that it doesn't go to the case START all it does is outputs the first line when I choose Heather

Comment: Can you update the code with the updated operators and I will look.

Comment: Also you already declare GameState = START in the beginning so why set it again in the if else if statement

Comment: Ok, the code is updated.

Comment: I also made "int GameState = START;" to "int GameState;" :)

Comment: whoops forgot to write the @ than the name.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, `==` is used to test for equality, while `=` is used to assign values. In your case, you try to assign the value `true` to `Anakin`, but you use the `==` operator instead. I suspect that changing the lines `Anakin == false;` and `Anakin == true;` to `Anakin = false;` and `Anakin = true;` might fix your issue.

Comment: Nothing changed.

Comment: I think you're also missing a closing bracket for the if-statement `if (Anakin == true) {`

Comment: I checked, i'm not missing one.